# Source for the Chazon Ish saying that long jackets are preferable?

Tags: minhag, clothing, tznius-modesty, chazon-ish

I have heard it first hand from no less than two different rabbis, and seen it in various places (unsourced*) that the Chazon Ish held that short jackets were not tznius, and this is why certain Litvaks who hold by the Chazon Ish in Bnei Brak and elsewhere do not wear short jackets like the rest of the Litvish world.

Did the Chazon Ish say this?

*This includes the ArtScroll Chazon Ish biography as well as the Chazon Ish Haggadah. But neither of those books are primary sources.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50590/759

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30224/which-shita-are-those-wearing-extra-long-tallit-katan-following